# How to implicitly refer to a variable

Tags: ruby, implicit, receiver

My code has a lot of this: `driver.blahblahblah`. Consider the following code sample, taken from http://www.browserstack.com/automate/ruby.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'    
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote,
  :url => "http://USERNAME:ACCESS_KEY@hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub")
driver.navigate.to "http://www.google.com/ncr"
element = driver.find_element(:name, 'q')
element.submit
puts driver.title
driver.quit
```

How can I make `driver` implicit? For example there's a method called `driver.save_screenshot()`. I want to say `save_screenshot("a.png")` because only the `driver` variable/object has this method.

Comment: Referring to an object is *not* repeating yourself. Repeating yourself is when you find yourself copy-pasting similar chunks of code in multiple places.

Comment: Your situation is not clear. Is the implicit receiver the same object among several methods, or are you asking the receiver to be automatically looked up depending on the method?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `delegate` from ActiveSupport like the example below:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/module/delegation'

class MyClass
  delegate :find_element, :save_screenshot, to: :driver

  def foo
    find_element
    save_screenshot
  end

  def driver
    @driver ||= Driver.new
  end
end

class Driver
  def find_element
    puts "find_element"
  end

  def save_screenshot
    puts "save_screenshot"
  end
end

MyClass.new.foo
```

Or decorate the driver using [SimpleDelegator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/SimpleDelegator.html) (but I don't recommend that).

Comment: Why is `SimpleDelegator` bad?

Comment: You'd get the whole decorated object public interface using SimpleDelegator, and  bloated api's are almost never a good idea. You would also have to pay attention to never override a method used by the decorated object.

Comment: Oh, `SimpleDelegator` is not generally bad - I meant that using it to solve this kind of problem is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of methods whose receiver is `driver`, then a way to make the receivers implicit is:

```
driver.instance_eval do
  method_1...
  method_2...
  ...
end
```

but notice that this slows down a little. If you are just finding a way to be lazy, then the best way is to make the local variable as short as a single letter, and do not bother making it implicit.

```
d = .... # instead of `drive`
d.method_1...
d.method_2...
...
```